# How can I set a ListView's selected item based on it's ID in a query string on page load?

Tags: asp.net, listview, selecteditem

Question basically crams it all in... I'm loading a page with a querystring (ID), and I need to use that ID to set the selected item of a ListView when the page loads. The ID is a DataKey on the ListView. Please help!

I have no code of value to post--none of my attempts at this work.

Comment: Take a look at this Q - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/570801/programmatically-select-item-in-asp-net-listview

Comment: @RPM1984 - That's got me closer than I've been yet, but I still have a problem. Both my ItemTemplate and SelectedItemTemplate have a LinkButton whose Text property is Eval("Description"), but when I implement this solution, the LinkButton has no text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first answer was not so clever, mixed up listbox and listview, so i'll try again:

```
ListView1.DataSource = New String() {"i1", "i2", "i3", "i4", "i5"}
ListView1.SelectedIndex = 3
ListView1.DataBind()
```

if i put the second line last it does not work, Databind has to be called after setting the selectedindex, but you can also call Databind a second time, after setting the SelectedIndex

Comment: My ListView's items collection doesn't have a FindByValue routine...?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this untested from memory

```
sId = Request.QueryString("id")
if NOT( string.NotisnullorEmpty(sId)) then
  Listbox.SelectedValue = sId
end if
```

Comment: This is a ListView, not ListBox. It has no SelectedValue property.

Comment: @zk812 - ListView does have a SelectedValue property, but that property only defines the get, not the set (so you can't change it for the ListView like you can for the ListBox).